# Filter user journey using user_id on firebase analytics

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I want to track the user journey for each unique user. At the moment my app is firing firebase events on each action that I want to track. I just need to filter the user journey against the user_id on firebase analytics.

I have set the user_id using setUserId and I have also tried to create custom audience by using this filter but there is no such event of user_id in audience.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**firebaser here*

The user_id has been purposefully removed from the Audience Builder due to privacy concerns.

Also, Analytics is not the best tool for tracking individual users, as it is made for analyzing users in aggregate.

You might want to consider using BigQuery export and query for the user_id value. You could visit this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9213390) for your reference. Also, you can find BigQuery's export schema in this [article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846).